# Not able to proceed with cq launcher

Tags: aem, experience-manager

I have created a launcher which invokes a workflow on creation of an asset of type dam:asset but when I am trying to run the workflow in Publish instance, replicating image from author the workflow is not getting invoked am I doing something wrong? is there a workaround?

Comment: There is run mode associated with launcher, what is the value of run mode of the launcher?

Comment: publish, I tried with author and publish as well

Comment: Any error in logs?

Comment: no error, when I run workflow on payload it is working fine there is something wrong with launcher I guess,
I made run mode to author on publish instance and workflow started working

Comment: Can you add screenshot of launcher config?