# AEM Launcher run mode issue in Publish Instance

Tags: adobe, aem

I am running a launcher in publish instance,the launcher doesn't invoke the workflow when run mode is publish or publish and author but it works when I make run mode as author
Can someone help me with this behaviour of AEM?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to proceed with cq launcher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119558/not-able-to-proceed-with-cq-launcher)

Answer (score 0):

Wrokflow launchers are tied to run-modes and you can change the behavior to run to either or both of them. The default dialog height is less hence it is not visible you need to scroll down.

[image: Default launcher full height]

Comment: The problem is workflow is getting invoked on publish instance only when runmode value is "author" it is not getting invoked on making runmode value as " publish" or "author and publish"

Comment: Then may be your machines run mode is not properly set, check http://localhost:4502/system/console/status-slingsettings what is the run mode displayed there.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the Adobe documentation:

*When using one of the above run modes (author, publish, samplecontent, nosamplecontent), the value used at installation time defines the run mode for the entire lifetime of that installation.
For these run modes you cannot change them after installation.*

You cannot use runmodes author AND publish at the same time (I wonder what AEM will do if you try to set both runmodes) and switching the runmode is also a bad idea.
See https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/deploy/configuring/configure-runmodes.html for details.

There must be something wrong with your instance. Any log messages?